# Why shlok from Gita addresses third person instead of second?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, vedanta, upanishads, sanskrit, language

> उद्धरेदात्मनात्मानं नात्मानमवसादयेत् |
>   आत्मैव ह्यात्मनो बन्धुरात्मैव रिपुरात्मन: || 5||
>
> Elevate yourself through the power of your mind, and not degrade yourself, for the mind can be the friend and also the enemy of the self.

Consider this sloka, here the dhatu roop 
'उद्धरेत्' and 'अवसादयेत्', so they are प्रथम पुरुष एकवचन विधि लिङ, but the translation addresses the second person. My queries are :

> 1.Sri Krishna was addressing Arjuna then why does he use the third person 
>    instead of the second person?
>
> 2. Why does translation defer from word-to-word pedantic translation ?

Comment: I expect a really profound answer for this question

Comment: Translation by Swami Gambhirananda: 6.5 One should save oneself by oneself; one should not lower oneself. For oneself is verily one's own friend; oneself is verily one's own enemy.

Comment: Translation by Swami Adidevananda: 6.5 One should raise the self by his own mind and not allow the self to sink; for the mind alone is the friend of the self, and the mind alone is the foe of the self.

Comment: So the translation is wrong !

Comment: I think the meaning remains the same whether it is inferred from point of view of individual or all .  It can be translated /inferred in either way @Kutsit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will answer your second question.

**1)Why does translation defer from word-to-word pedantic translation ?**

There can be a problem with your translation. I am not saying anything about translator because I don't know whose translation you quoted. Many times very great Sanskrit scholars can even do this mistake. But for your satisfaction, I am quoting International Gita society translation here.

> One must elevate and not degrade oneself by one’s own mind. The mind alone is one’s friend as well as one’s enemy.

**2)Sri Krishna was addressing Arjuna then why does he use the third person instead of the second person?**

In this verse Lord Krishna is giving teaching to everyone. It is a wisdomful teaching for everyone for example when a father says to his child that "Everyone should speak truth" there is nothing wrong. By doing this he cleared that this teaching is not only for Arjuna but for whole human race.
Jai Shri Krishna